# Foursquare Realtime API when someone checks into a venue

Tags: real-time, push-notification, foursquare

I multiple venues and I'd like to receive a push notification for when user(s) check-in.  For example, the web site will display a message: "4 people checked-in to the LA Fitness".  I'd like the results to be in realtime so the site will constantly be updating.  I've looked at the Foursquare API and couldn't find anything realtime and updating.

Can this be done in PHP or nodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  Foursquare released a Push API at their last hackathon (*Edit:* March, 2011). You may have to email the support team to get access, but they're very accommodating people and I'm sure they would love to hep you out.

Also, here is a link to an example consumer written in Python:

> https://github.com/nsanch/foursquare-push-api-sample

**P.S.** For anyone interested, here is the article on the hackathon and the Push API

> http://blog.foursquare.com/2011/02/22/stop-hacker-time/

Comment: Thanks Mike!  Do you know the support team's email address?

Comment: api@foursquare.com (Also, please see this link https://github.com/foursquare/hackathon/wiki/Foursquare-Push-API)